# Getting error while trying to use node module to add unique slug in a node for neo4j database?

Tags: node.js, neo4j

In Node.js environment,I am using neo4j dB. I want to create unique slug using node module "uslug" for each of the node in neo4j . But I am getting an error while trying to use this function in cypher query in my js file.
My query :

```
var uslug = require("uslug")
var slug = `MERGE(t:Test) set t.Blogtitle= uslug('Testing Slug','-')`
```

// FYI, for the sake of readability I have not added the codes related to neo4j drivers here...

**So,how should I use the uslug function such that unique slug would be created for each of node in neo4j** ? And even if the same Blogtitle exists already,how do I set the slug to increment like "Testing-Slug-1" ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Neo4jError: Unknown function 'uslug'. This is the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error

> Neo4jError: Unknown function 'uslug'. This is the error

because Neo4j don't know about the function `uslug` and you are passing it into a Cypher query. You should call `uslug` in the node.js context, not in the Neo4j database.

Try it:

```
var uslug = require("uslug")
var slug = "MERGE(t:Test) set t.Blogtitle='" + uslug('Testing Slug') + "'"
```

That is: call `uslug('Testing Slug')` and concat the result with the Cypher query.

Also, according the [code samples](https://github.com/jeremys/uslug#quick-examples) the second parameter should be an optional object, not a string as you are using. So you should fix the function call to `uslug('Testing Slug')`.

Comment: I tried to concatenate but I am getting this error: TypeError: (0 , _uslug.uslug) is not a function..What should I do?

Comment: @CodeReactor according to [uslug code examples](https://github.com/jeremys/uslug#quick-examples) the second argument should be an object. It is optional. But you are passing a string `'-'`. So I believe you should remove the second parameter and use `uslug('Testing Slug')` instead.

Comment: I figured that part out thanks..And How should I increment the count if the same Blogtitle is present twice. For e.g.: If BlogTitle="Testing slug" is added in 2 different nodes.I wish to increment the count of the second BlogTitle by 1 i.e. "Testing-slug-1"...Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance !!

Comment: @CodeReactor I believe this is another question, so I suggest you ask a new question instead of using the comments. But a good approach to avoid duplicates is concatenating an integer based on the current date-time, something like `testing-slug-20170914125500`, indication the date and time 2017-09-14 12:55:00.

Comment: @CodeReactor Also, if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.